# Is there any way to hide a log in cypress?

Tags: javascript, cypress

I'd like to know if there's a way to not show a log in Cypress, for example.

If I make a test to log into any application, when it types the password:

```
cy.get(#id).type(password)
```

and the test is executed, the password value appears in the log.

Is there any way of stopping this?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

as per [docs](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/type.html#Arguments), this should work:

```
cy.get("#id").type( password, { log: false });
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to hide the command log sidebar altogether then set the ENV `CYPRESS_NO_COMMAND_LOG` to `1` before running Cypress this way:

```
CYPRESS_NO_COMMAND_LOG=1 cypress run
```

[Documentation](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/troubleshooting#Disable-the-Command-Log)

[image: before-after]

It works for the Cypress v10.9.0
With some older versions (8.7.0, 9.6.0) it may not work.

- [CYPRESS_NO_COMMAND_LOG=1 leaves faulty empty space](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/21271)
- [fix: respect CYPRESS_NO_COMMAND_LOG in env](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/pull/22641)

Answer (score -2):

We can hide the details of each step inside `cy.getIframeBody` code by disabling internal commands' logging.

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('getIframeBody', () => {
  // get the iframe > document > body
  // and retry until the body element is not empty
  cy.log('getIframeBody')

  return cy
  .get('iframe[data-cy="the-frame"]', { log: false })
  .its('0.contentDocument.body', { log: false }).should('not.be.empty')
  // wraps "body" DOM element to allow
  // chaining more Cypress commands, like ".find(...)"
  // https://on.cypress.io/wrap
  .then((body) => cy.wrap(body, { log: false }))
})
```

[image: Output will be look like this]

Comment: Although your answer includes the solution, it is very convoluted